# Retrieve data from database and show in detailsview

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sharepoint

I want to retrieve data from database on the current logged in SharePoint user and show it on a control in a detailsview. But I really don't know how to achieve that on the best way. This is a code I've tried but it shows `null`.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetEmployeeCv();
        }
    }

    private void GetEmployeeCv()
    {
        using (var db = new KnowItCvdbEntities())
        {
            SPWeb theSite = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);
            SPUser theUser = theSite.CurrentUser;
            string strUserName = theUser.LoginName;

            var theEmpl =(from p in db.EMPLOYEES
                          where p.username == strUserName
                         select p).FirstOrDefault();

            if(theEmpl != null)
            {
                Image empImg = (Image)DetailsViewShowFullCv.FindControl("imageProfPic");
                empImg.ImageUrl = theEmpl.image;                    
            }
        }            
    }
```

If I want to databind my detailsview like:

```
                Image empImg = (Image)DetailsViewShowFullCv.FindControl("imageProfPic");
                empImg.ImageUrl = theEmpl.image;                    

                DetailsViewShowFullCv.DataSource = ??;
                DetailsViewShowFullCv.DataBind();
```

I don't really know how to do it. Anyone out there that can help me out?

Comment: I would like to know which other variables are null. Is strUserName null?

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://www.learn-asp.net/asptutorials/detailsview.aspx), it has all the visual cues I was looking to type as an answer. I've deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

a)  The DataSource should be the variable which holds the data.  In this case it would be theEmpl

b)  Run this through the debugger to check if strUserName is what you expect.  The LoginName field typically returns the domain and username like "DOMAIN\UserName" so there's a chance that it will return a null (null by default) value if you're only storing the UserName part in the database without the Domain\

c)  For Databinding, either change your LINQ query to p.FieldNameToDatabind or know how to write the Databind code in asp markup so that you can actually display the field.